# Relational algebra question

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic, relation-algebra

Suppose we are given the following binary relations on a set $A$:

$$S \triangleleft R = \{(x,y) \mid \forall z\,(R(y,z) \to S(x,z)\,) \} $$
$$S \circ R = \{(x,y) \mid \exists z\,(R(x,z) \land S(z,y)\,) \} $$

and need to prove

$$(R \triangleleft T) \circ (S \triangleleft R) \subseteq (S \triangleleft T) $$

I think this cannot be proven. Suppose that $(x,y) \in (R \triangleleft T) \circ (S \triangleleft R)$ and $(x,y) \not\in (S \triangleleft T)$.

Decomposing the relations we end up with the question of whether the following formula of predicate logic is consistent:

$$\exists z \,(\forall z' (S(z,z') \to R(x,z')) \land \forall z''(R(y, z'') \to T(z, z'')\,) \land \neg (\forall z(S(y,z) \to T(x,z)\,)\,)\, ) $$

If it is inconsistent then $(x,y) \in S \triangleleft T$. However, I can't prove the formula inconsistent. I'm therefore wondering if

$$(R \triangleleft T) \circ (S \triangleleft R) \subseteq (S \triangleleft T) $$

is not in fact provable. I would appreciate any help with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that $(x,y) \in (R \triangleleft T) \circ (S \triangleleft R).$ Then there exists $z$ such that $(x,z) \in S \triangleleft R$ and $(z,y) \in R \triangleleft T,$ i.e. for all $w$ we have $R(y,w)\rightarrow S(x,w)$ and $T(y,w)\rightarrow R(z,w).$ Combining these, for all $w$ we have $T(y,w)\rightarrow S(x,w),$ i.e. $(x,y) \in S\triangleleft T.$ Thus, $(R \triangleleft T) \circ (S \triangleleft R) \subseteq S\triangleleft T.$

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't use the definition of $\circ$ I provided. It is relative to that specific definition of $\circ$ that I was doubting the inclusion.

Comment: In what way doesn't it use that definition, do you think?

Comment: Because according to the definition of $\circ$ I gave, we start with the right most relation, not the leftmost relation as you have done, so that $(x,y) \in (R \triangleleft T) \circ (S \triangleleft R)$ would imply $\exists z((x,z) \in S \triangleleft R \land (z,y) \in R \triangleleft T)$.

Comment: Ah, now I see. I'll have a second look at it then.

Comment: @Edward.Lin. I found that I also got the order wrong when applying the definition of $\triangleleft$. After fixing both errors, the proof still seemed to work. Please have a look.